# Entity Framework, update multiple fields more efficiently

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-update

Using Entity Framework, I am updating about 300 rows, and 9 columns about every 30 seconds. Below is how I am currently doing it. My question is, how can I make the code more efficient?

Every once in a while, I feel my database gets hit with the impact and I just want to make it as efficient as possible.

```
// FOREACH OF MY 300 ROWS
var original = db.MarketDatas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BBSymbol == targetBBsymbol);

if (original != null)
{
    //if (original.BBSymbol.ToUpper() == "NOH7 INDEX")
    //{
    //    var x1 = 1;
    //}

    original.last_price = marketDataItem.last_price;
    original.bid = marketDataItem.bid;
    original.ask = marketDataItem.ask;

    if (marketDataItem.px_settle_last_dt_rt != null)
    {
        original.px_settle_last_dt_rt = marketDataItem.px_settle_last_dt_rt;
    }

    if (marketDataItem.px_settle_actual_rt != 0)
    {
        original.px_settle_actual_rt = marketDataItem.px_settle_actual_rt;
    }

    original.chg_on_day = marketDataItem.chg_on_day;

    if (marketDataItem.prev_close_value_realtime != 0)
    {
        original.prev_close_value_realtime = marketDataItem.prev_close_value_realtime;
    }

    if (marketDataItem.px_settle_last_dt_rt != null)
    {
        DateTime d2 = (DateTime)marketDataItem.px_settle_last_dt_rt;

        if (d1.Day == d2.Day)
        {
            //market has settled
            original.settled = "yes";
        }
        else
        {
            //market has NOT settled
            original.settled = "no";
        }
    }

    if (marketDataItem.updateTime.Year != 1)
    {
        original.updateTime = marketDataItem.updateTime;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Watching what is being hit in the debugger...

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[MarketDataID] AS [MarketDataID], 
[Extent1].[BBSymbol] AS [BBSymbol], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[fut_Val_Pt] AS [fut_Val_Pt], 
[Extent1].[crncy] AS [crncy], 
[Extent1].[fut_tick_size] AS [fut_tick_size], 
[Extent1].[fut_tick_val] AS [fut_tick_val], 
[Extent1].[fut_init_spec_ml] AS [fut_init_spec_ml], 
[Extent1].[last_price] AS [last_price], 
[Extent1].[bid] AS [bid], 
[Extent1].[ask] AS [ask], 
[Extent1].[px_settle_last_dt_rt] AS [px_settle_last_dt_rt], 
[Extent1].[px_settle_actual_rt] AS [px_settle_actual_rt], 
[Extent1].[settled] AS [settled], 
[Extent1].[chg_on_day] AS [chg_on_day], 
[Extent1].[prev_close_value_realtime] AS [prev_close_value_realtime], 
[Extent1].[last_tradeable_dt] AS [last_tradeable_dt], 
[Extent1].[fut_notice_first] AS [fut_notice_first], 
[Extent1].[updateTime] AS [updateTime]
FROM [dbo].[MarketDatas] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[BBSymbol] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[BBSymbol] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
```

It seems it updates the same thing multiple times, if I am understanding it correctly.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MarketDatas]
SET [last_price] = @0, [chg_on_day] = @1, [updateTime] = @2
WHERE ([MarketDataID] = @3)

UPDATE [dbo].[MarketDatas]
SET [last_price] = @0, [chg_on_day] = @1, [updateTime] = @2
WHERE ([MarketDataID] = @3)
```

Comment: Why do you think it updates the same thing? Have you missed the parameters inside `UPDATE` SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce this to 2 round trips.

1. Don't call `SaveChanges()` in side the loop. Move it outside and call it after you are done processing everything.
2. Write the select in such a way that it retrieves all the originals in one go and pushes them to a memory collection, then retrieve from that for each item you are updating/inserting.

**code**

```
// use this as your source
// to retrieve an item later use TryGetValue
var originals = db.MarketDatas
  .Where(x => arrayOftargetBBsymbol.Contains(x.BBSymbol));
  .ToDictionary(x => x.BBSymbol, y => y);

// iterate over changes you want to make
foreach(var change in changes){
    MarketData original = null;

    // is there an existing entity
    if(originals.TryGetValue(change.targetBBsymbol, out original)){
        // update your original
    }
}

// save changes all at once
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: just so I follow you, you grab all the original like you have above, then update the values in that var originals... then how do you push this original to overwrite the db?

Comment: @solarissf - with a call to `SaveChanges` but outside the loop. The `DbContext` tracks all retrieved entities by default so make changes in your loop and then after the loop call SaveChanges and it will push all changes back to the store.

Comment: @solarissf - I updated my code, maybe this is more clear for you?

Comment: this was perfect... I changed around my code and it seems to be much faster.  I have to watch it for a few days to see amount of db hits but this seems to have solved my issue... thanks!  the extra code you wrote helped tremendously

Comment: @solarissf - glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You could only execute "db.SaveChanges" after your foreach loop. It think it you would do exactly what your are asking for.

Comment: that helped, but I also changed around my code like @Igor stated.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems it updates the same thing multiple times, if I am
>   understanding it correctly.

Entity Framework performs a database round-trip for every entity to update.

Just check the parameter value, they will be different.

> how can I make the code more efficient

The major problem is your current solution is not scalable.

It works well when you only have a few entities to update but will become worse and worse are the number of items to update in a batch will increase.

It's often better to make this kind of logic all in the database, but perhaps you cannot do it.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library can make your code more efficient by allowing you to save multiples entities at once. All bulk operations are supported:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge
- BulkSynchronize

Example:

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(customers, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```